# How do I remove tiny pixel borders from bootstrap image grid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a image tile grid using Bootstrap 3.7. All the cols have a figure inside with a background image set to cover everything 100%. The grid is meant to have all images right up against each other and have no gaps at all.

Problem is, when resizing the window into certain resolutions I get these little (approx 1px gaps) appearing in the grid and I cannot seem to get rid of them. They become way more prominent on the figcaption element.

Here a sample of the HTML code (repeats through columns):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <a href="#" class="rwp-site">
        <figure class="project-box" style="background-color: purple">
          <figcaption>
            <div class="site-title">
              <p>
              Site title #1
              </p>
            </div>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the css:

```
.container {
  background: aqua;
}

.col-xl-2, .col-lg-3, .col-md-4, .col-sm-6 .col-xs-12 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
.project-box {
    height: 360px;
    /* background-color: #ccc; */
    background-size: cover;
    filter: grayscale(0);
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.project-box:hover {
    filter: grayscale(1);
    transform: scale(0.98);
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    color: white;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'didact', sans-serif;
}
.rwp-site {
    display: block;
}
.rwp-site:hover figcaption {
    color: lightblue;
}
.rwp-site:before { bottom: 10px; left: 10px; }
.rwp-site figcaption { left: 0; bottom: 0; }

figcaption .site-title {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

figcaption p {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.col-md-12.sites-sorting-menu, .bc-footer .col-md-12 {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle I made to recreate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/coolwebs/s4531dmb/1/ if you resize the display window, you will see the small white gaps appearing, especially between the figcaptions.

Is there any way of getting rid of these small gaps? Is it a bootstrap issue happening because of the way it divides up the columns?

Comment: can you please explain it more clear. What I observed in fiddle I dont see any white gap,and  your problem is about when we resize the window, a small white gaps appearing between figcaptions.

Comment: Try comment the   `/* transform: scale(1); */` in `.project-box` class

Comment: Oh yeah, just noticed the images are behind a firewall (whoops). However without the images, you can notice the small gaps when zooming out of the browser (i.e. CNTRL/CMD +/- or using mouse wheel) https://jsfiddle.net/s4531dmb/4/. Perhaps it is a rendering issue?

Answer (score 1):

Was quite a strange issue, perhaps almost an 'edge case'. My solution was to add tiny negative margins on either sides of the column:

```
.col-xl-2, .col-lg-3, .col-md-4, .col-sm-6 .col-xs-12 {
margin-left: -0.5px;
margin-right: -0.5px;
}
```

Comment: Negative margin resolved in my case as well. I was setting adjacent columns to use the same background color but seeing a one pixel gap between the columns. I think the issue has to do with how the browser (Chrome in my case) calculates column max-widths. I think the browser is (probably correctly) using floor instead of ceiling. In my case, I created an additional class `.mr-nfix` with CSS `margin-right: -1px` so that I could keep the left edge aligned and apply a negative margin only to the columns that needed the fix.